# Microsoft.Data.Analysis DataFrame - What is the idiomatic way to fill one column with manipulated values from another?

Tags: c#

C# 10 / .NET 6 / Microsoft.Data.Analysis

Given a `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` `DataFrame` with two columns, what is the idiomatic way to take values from one column, manipulate them, then use the resulting value to fill the rows of the second column element-wise?

```
        // Create a DateTime column.
        PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<DateTime> dateTimeCol = new("Dates", 0);
        // Fill it.
        dateTimeCol.Append(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        dateTimeCol.Append(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
        dateTimeCol.Append(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(3));

        // Create a Ticks column.
        PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<long> ticksCol = new("Ticks", dateTimeCol.Length);

        // Create a DataFrame of the above two columns.
        DataFrame df = new();
        df.Columns.Add(dateTimeCol);
        df.Columns.Add(ticksCol);
```

At this point, what I want to do is `df["Ticks"] = df["Dates"].Ticks`.  Of course, this doesn't work.  I could do this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < df.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime tempDate = (DateTime) df[i, df.Columns.IndexOf("Dates")];
            df[i, df.Columns.IndexOf("Ticks")] = tempDate.Ticks;
        }
```

But... is there a better way?